# What is the common preimage (in $Z$) and the equivalence relation for Pushouts

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_%28category_theory%29) it says: Suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ as above are sets, and that $f : Z → X$ and $g : Z → Y$ are set functions. The pushout of $f$ and $g$ is the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$, where elements sharing a common preimage (in $Z$) are identified, together with certain morphisms from X and Y.

I do not understand this part "the pushout of $f$ and $g$ is the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$, *where elements sharing a common preimage (in $Z$) are identified"*. Question: To form the Pushout you get the disjoint union and then what?

Comment: It seems that you need to mod out by the relation $(x,1)\sim (y,2) \iff f^{-1}(x) = g^{-1}(y)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That's not quite right; $(x,1)$ and $(y,2)$ will be identified so long as $f^{-1}(x) \cap g^{-1}(y) \ne \varnothing$, since then there will exist $z \in Z$ such that $f(z)=x$ and $g(z)=y$. We don't need to require $f(z)=x \Leftrightarrow g(z)=y$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead ah, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I suppose we should formalise disjoint union; I'll say
$$X \sqcup Y = (X \times \{ 0 \}) \cup (Y \times \{ 1 \})$$
so that each $x \in X$ corresponds with $(x,0) \in X \sqcup Y$ and each $y \in Y$ corresponds with $(y,1) \in X \sqcup Y$. The $0$ and $1$ are redundant apart from the fact that they ensure that the components of the above union are disjoint even if $X$ and $Y$ are not disjoint... imagine laying the set $X$ out on the ground (level $0$) and laying the set $Y$ out upstairs (level $1$).

We can define the pushout of $f$ and $g$ in the category of sets to be the set
$$P = (X \sqcup Y) / {\sim}$$
where $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation satisfying $(f(z),0) \sim (g(z),1)$ for all $z \in Z$. That is, $\sim$ takes the disjoint union and glues together points downstairs in $X$ and points upstairs in $Y$: it identifies two points if and only if there is some point in $Z$ that they both come from.

To put it another way, $\sim$ is the least equivalence relation such that $(x,0) \sim (y,1)$ whenever $f^{-1} (\{ x \}) \cap g^{-1} (\{ y \}) \ne \varnothing$.

---

**Example.** Let $Z = \{ a,b \}$ and let $X = Y = \mathbb{Z}$. Define $f : \{ a,b \} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and $g : \{ a,b \} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by
$$f(a) = 5, \quad f(b) = 6,$$
$$g(a) = 7, \quad g(b) = 8$$
Now the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ is just two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e.
$$X \sqcup Y = \{ (n,i) : n \in \mathbb{Z},\ i \in \{ 0,1 \} \}$$

The equivalence relation is going to identify every element with itself, together with
$$(5,0) \sim (7,1) \quad \text{and} \quad (6,0) \sim (8,1)$$
since $5 = f(a)$ and $7=g(a)$, and $6=f(b)$ and $8=g(b)$.

The pushout is then $\mathbb{Z} \cup \mathbb{Z}$, except with $(5,0)$ and $(7,1)$ regarded as the same element, and $(6,0)$ and $(8,1)$ regarded as the same element (since they lie in the same $\sim$-equivalence class).

---

**Another example.** Let $X=Y=S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be unit circles in the plane and let $Z = \{ a \}$. Define $f(a)=g(a)=(1,0)$. Thus $f$ and $g$ just pick out a point on the circle.

From a geometric perspective, $X \sqcup Y$ is what you get when you lie two circles next to each other in such a way that they don't overlap. The pushout of $f$ and $g$ identifies $f(a) \in X$ with $g(a) \in Y$, i.e. it joins together the two points.

The pushout is thus a figure-eight shape.

Comment: I see the general idea but I do not understand the gluing part.Is it possible to have a (very)small example with integers?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer. Do you know about quotienting by equivalence relations? Because that would probably help... when I write $(X \sqcup Y) / {\sim}$ I mean the set of $\sim$-equivalence classes. Anyway I'll give an example in a sec.

Comment: The only thing I know about quotient sets is that you've got a set of sets where each set is an equivalence class? Thank you very much btw

Comment: @asqweq: No problem. I've updated my answer. You can think of it as being a set of sets (those sets are equivalence classes), but geometrically you can think of what you get when you squish each equivalence class to a single point.

Comment: @Clive: Your description of $\sim$ is not correct. You have to consider chains (transitve closure), too. $f(z) = f(z') \sim g(z') = g(z'') \sim \dotsc$, you know? If $f$ or $g$ are injective, we don't need these chains (fortunately! this is actually quite important as for the definition of CW-complexes..).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Oh yeah, I thought that something was missing. I'll remove that part from my post, it doesn't really help the intuition anyway.

Comment: "To put it another way, (x,0)∼(y,1) if and only if f−1({x})∩g−1({y})≠∅." is still wrong.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: One of these days I'll get it right... I've edited my post again.

Comment: @CliveNewstead The equivalence relation does not seem to be defined concretely to me. It seems like we are only relating some element of $X$ to some element of $Y$: $(x,0) \sim (y,1) \iff f^{-1} (\{ x \}) \cap g^{-1} (\{ y \}) \ne \varnothing$. Although transitivity guarantees us two elements from $X$ can be related, the equivalence relation definition itself does not define when two elements of the same set are related.

Comment: @AlJebr: This answer is over five years old. In any case, I re-read my answer and I can't see anything wrong with it. I think you're saying the same thing that I was saying in my answer. Note my use of the word 'least': I'm saying $\sim$ is the equivalence relations [*generated by*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Generating_equivalence_relations) declaring $(x,0) \sim (y,1)$ whenever $f^{-1}[\{x\}] \cap g^{-1}[\{y\}] \ne \varnothing$. Of course $\sim$ will relate other pairs, of elements of $X \sqcup Y$ too.